# How to use Supabase RLS with third-party client library?

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I'm using Supabase as my database, with RLS turned on. I query the DB from a Node backend using the [postgres.js](https://github.com/porsager/postgres) client (it could be any other JS client really). As such I'm connecting direct with the default postgres user and I issue raw SQL queries.

How can I query my DB while still maskerading as a user from Supa's auth.users table? I have triggers and RLS policies that take advantage of the current logged-in user, via Supa's auth.uid() function.

All I can find online is that I must set the `current_user_id` postgres setting to the current Supabase user, but I don't grasp the implications of that, from a functional and security perspective. I wouldn't want to leak the current user to another session.

Comment: Could you share some extra details?  Do you want to connect using a driver to send direct SQL commands? 
What is the client that you would use? Do you have a default user for this or do you want to set somethings for a super user service?